# JS execution time

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, profiling, execution-time

My site is pretty standard ecom site, it isn't a JS backed standalone app or anything, it's just a site which uses JS for standard stuff, as well as some jquery plugins to do a few things.

I've used Chrome Dev Tools to take some CPU profiles.

Most of my functions are low key operations, and don't exceed 200ms.

What is a good benchmark I should be aiming for? Is 200ms high?

Comment: This StackOverflow page is rendering 1.13 seconds in my browser. You still have some extra time ;)

Comment: If you get 200ms on a fresh i7-powered desktop, try browsing your site on a cheap Android tablet or the 1st gen iPad. Or you are not targeting mobile users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

200ms isn't too bad, but you should try to keep your JavaScript interactions under 100ms. The browser UI only has a single thread for updating the both UI and for executing JavaScript (only on can happen at a time). So the longer your JavaScript runs the worse the user experience.

**0.1 second** is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously, meaning that no special feedback is necessary except to display the result.

**1.0 second** is about the limit for the user's flow of thought to stay uninterrupted, even though the user will notice the delay. Normally, no special feedback is necessary during delays of more than 0.1 but less than 1.0 second, but the user does lose the feeling of operating directly on the data.

**10 seconds** is about the limit for keeping the user's attention focused on the dialogue. For longer delays, users will want to perform other tasks while waiting for the computer to finish, so they should be given feedback indicating when the computer expects to be done. Feedback during the delay is especially important if the response time is likely to be highly variable, since users will then not know what to expect.

-Jakob Nielsen

There are several patterns for breaking up work that needs to be done into chunks so you don't get the dreaded "Unresponsive script" error. Such as using timers, or web workers etc, but the implementation depends on what your code needs to do. You're on the right tracking using the Dev Tools to gain some insight into what's going on!